# UICollectionView horizontal scrolling ui bug

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have code like this for my collection view

```
 let collectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cv.isPagingEnabled = true
    cv.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    cv.backgroundColor = .white
    return cv
}()
```

And I want to show 5 items in this collection view horizontally while paging having 4 items on a page. It works fine when I scroll to the next page which will contain my 2nd to 5th items but then comes the bug. If I just tap on the second page it will auto-scroll to my first page. This isn't an issue when I have a total of six items and the second-page shows 3rd to 6th items. It seems to occur when the second page has fewer items to display like in my first example.

Can anybody help me with this bug?

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWxR3.gif)

```
class VC: UIViewController {
    // add collectionView to view in viewDidLoad
    view.addSubView(collectionView)
}

extension VC: UICollectionViewDelegate { }

extension VC: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        4
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
}

extension VC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.width / 3, height: collectionView.bounds.height)
    }
}
```

Comment: it would be great if you post code, which is compileable and runnable so that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: I added a gif for the example and nothing unique is done to code. Just adding the collectionView to the main view with delegate setup and number of items set as 4 with flowdelegate (size of item = width of an item is a third of the width of the collectionView and height is same as collectionView)

Comment: ok, please, if you want help, add your code here, so we can help you. Why do you think i got 3 upvotes for my first comment? please read and consider(!) this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. This is NOT a "we write code for you for free" - platform, but a platform where we help you with your code. if you do not post runnable code, don't expect somebody wants to help you.....and the gif does not help anything.